# How do I grab what is written to console with CSharpCodeProvider

Tags: c#, csharpcodeprovider

I use following to compile C# in runtime:

```
CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters
        {
            GenerateInMemory = true,
            GenerateExecutable = true,
            IncludeDebugInformation =  true
        };


        // True - memory generation, false - external file generation
        // True - exe file generation, false - dll file generation

        var res = pro.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters,
            code);

        Assembly assembly = res.CompiledAssembly;
        Type program = assembly.GetType("First.Program");
        MethodInfo main = program.GetMethod("Main");
        var invoke = main?.Invoke(null, null);
```

`res.Output` is an empty list, and If the code has `Console.WriteLine()`, It gets written to main application's console, however; I wanna grab what is written.

Answer (score 0):

You also should check `res.Errors`. If there are errors, then they will be there instead.  If both `Errors` and `Output` are empty, then you may have had a successful compilation without any output. Check: `cr.NativeCompilerReturnValue.ToString()`

Comment: There are no errors, and it writes to parent application's debug, but I wanna fetch it instead.

Comment: @TalhaTalipAçıkgöz Not sure what would cause that.  You could use a debug listener: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.listeners(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I will take a look, but I think there should be a better way.

Comment: I made it an external file, and with a process, read the stream; still thanks for the help.